# Is it possible to find the repeating patterns in the TEXT stored in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, statistics

Is it possible to find repeating patterns in the text?

**My table looks like this:**

```
CREATE TABLE `textanalysis` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `abstract` text,
    UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `abstract` (`abstract`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I would like to find the words or group of words in the text then make a statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some tricks (not very optimized)

use **"apple"** for example,
length for **apple** is 5

```
SELECT
  (LENGTH(abstract)-LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(abstract), 'apple', '')))/5 
  AS occurrences
FROM
  textanalysis
WHERE
  MATCH (abstract) AGAINST ('+apple' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

What is does is to replace **apple** (make the length of abstract shorter),
and you compare the original length to deduce number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so clear about your requirement, but if you want to count the occurrence of each distinct words, you can try

```
select count(id) as total_word, abstract from textanalysis group by abstract;
```

Comment: abstract is consists of **ALL words**